# How to toggle content in the rows in Material UI by default?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, toggle

I'am working with Muitables, my question is, how to display the expanded rows by default? like in the image below?

after opening the page, I would like to be the content in that row to be displayed by default (arrow down)

Thank you.
[image]

the code goes something like this:

```
const options = {
  expandableRows: true,
  fixedHeader: false,
  sort: false,
  filter: false,
  elevation: 1,
  download: false,
  print: false,
  search: false,
  viewColumns: false,
  rowsSelected: true,
  selectableRows: false,
  rowHover: false,
  responsive: 'scroll',

  customFooter: () => <React.Fragment />,
  renderExpandableRow: (rowData) => {
    
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <TableRow>   
          <TableCell>
              entry 1
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>
            entry 2
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

///////////////
and here's the column

```
export const Table => {
  
  const columns = [
    {
      name: 'fileName',
      label: 'File Name',
      options: {
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta) => {

              return (
                
                <div>

                  test column
                </div>
              )
                     
        }
      }
    },
 
  ]
  let arr= []
  // let hasPending = false
   testing.map((file, index) => {
     if(file.fileName !== ''){

          fileStatus=file.fileStatus
          arr.push(file)
     }
   })
  return ( 
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MUIDataTable
        title={title}
        data={arr}
        columns={columns}
        options={options}
      />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to toggle the current state of the button. If it is set to 'close' by default, you will have to switch it.

It would be better if you shared your code so that I can help you better.

Comment: Hi Winter, please check the edited version above.. Thanks

Comment: On clicking the 'down arrow', there could be 
`const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);`
written inside your onClick function. 
You will have to toggle that from 'false' to 'true'

Comment: Hi Winter, How? I've added the column part which displays the row to be click.. Thanks

Comment: I recommend checking this out: https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#collapsible-table